# Why did Mr Hinx attack Bond & Madeleine Swann on the train?

Tags: james-bond, spectre

It is eventually revealed in *Spectre* that the titular organisation possesses unprecidented levels of surveilance, and it is by virtue of this that Mr Hinx is able to track Bond across the globe.

However, Bond and Swann decide to confront the organisation and are on a train on the way to Spectre HQ when they are attacked by their pursuer.

**Why would he do this?**

The train is heading to a pretty desolate location, it's obvious that Bond is coming straight to Blofeld. What does Hinx have to gain in attacking/apprehending/murdering the couple on their way?

They have effectively been invited, it doesn't make sense as to why Hinx would choose to attack.

Answer (score 7):

I had a few theories:

1. They had their guard down which was a perfect time to attack.
2. Mr. Hinx is a bit of a loose canon, he essentially does what he wants (he gouges the eyes of his competitor without warning) and what he wants is to kill Bond. He's annoyed at Bond because he's made a fool of him twice by the time they meet on the train and he just wants to get his revenge.

I don't think Obenhauser really cared whether Bond died at his hand or not, up until he nearly killed him that is.